# « De moins » ou « en moins » ?

Tags: expressions, prépositions

> Il y a dix candidats ____ cette année que l'année dernière.

Devrait-on utiliser *de moins* ou *en moins* ici ?

De façon similaire, devrait-on utiliser *de plus* ou *en plus* ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Les deux locutions (avec *en* ou *de*) ont le même sens et s'emploient indifféremment:

[TLF.](http://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/moins) 2. c.

> a) Loc. adj. Subst./pronom./numéral + de moins (... que)/en moins. Qui manque, qui vient en diminution. *L'argent en moins et la diffamation en plus* (Fourier, Nouv. monde industr., 1830, p.31). *Elle a dix ans de moins que sa fille* (Zola, Nana, 1880, p.1426).
>   − [Pour signifier qu'un état ou une situation peut être (ou ne pas être) modifiée par une petite quantité] **Qqc. de/en plus ou de/en moins.** *Ce qu'elles ont en plus ou en moins dans un certain sens corrige ce que nous avons en moins ou en plus dans le sens contraire* (Sand, Hist. vie, t. 2, 1855, p.266). *Quelques gouttes d'eau de plus ou de moins ont fait pencher Napoléon* (Hugo, Misér., t. 1, 1862, p.374).

*Le Bon Usage* (10<sup>e</sup>, édition 851, a, 5) :

> *De moins*, parfois *en moins*, se disent pour exprimer l'idée de manque ou de diminution.

*Il y a dix candidats de moins/plus cette année*,  *il y a dix candidats en moins/en plus cette année* donc se disent.

Bien que *de plus* et *de moins* contiennent déjà en soi l'idée de comparaison, quand la deuxième partie de la comparaison est exprimée verbalement *(plus ... **que*** / *moins ... **que***), probablement à cause de la proximité du *que* (je ne connais pas de règle à ce sujet), l'usage est d'utiliser la construction avec **de**, même si on peut trouver *[en moins que](https://www.google.fr/search?as_q=%22de%20moins%22%20ou%20%22%20en%20moins%22&as_epq=&as_oq=&as_eq=&as_nlo=&as_nhi=&lr=&cr=&as_qdr=all&as_sitesearch=&as_occt=any&safe=images&as_filetype=&as_rights=#q=%22points%20en%20moins%20que%22&as_qdr=all&start=40)* / *[en plus que](https://www.google.fr/search?as_q=%22de%20moins%22%20ou%20%22%20en%20moins%22&as_epq=&as_oq=&as_eq=&as_nlo=&as_nhi=&lr=&cr=&as_qdr=all&as_sitesearch=&as_occt=any&safe=images&as_filetype=&as_rights=#q=%22points%20en%20plus%20que%22&as_qdr=all&start=0)*, ces occurrences restent marginales.

Donc si on ne veut pas être critiqué par les puristes il vaudrait mieux dire :

> Il y a dix candidats de plus / de moins cette année que l'année dernière.

Mais comme le dit @StéphaneGimenez, on n'intercalerait pas le complément de temps entre la locution et *que* mais on le placerait au début de la phrase, du moins à l'écrit.

> Cette année il y a dix candidats de plus / de moins que l'année dernière.

Comment: Euh ça me semble encore critiquable. Ce serait plutôt “Cette année, il y a dix candidats de plus que l'année dernière”. Intercaler un complément libre au milieu d'un autre ça parait très douteux.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Exact, j'ai repris l'ordre des mots de la question mais moi en effet je ne dirais jamais ça, du moins à l'écrit.

Answer (score 3):

Les deux sont acceptables, "de" est légèrement plus courant que "en" d'après ngram viewer.

Exemples:

> environ mille places **en** moins que l’année dernière [1](http://leconomiste.com/article/65279pelerinage-moins-de-places-que-l-annee-derniere)
>
> un tiers de détritus **en** moins que l'année dernière [2](http://www.larep.fr/chatillon-sur-loire/environnement/2017/03/07/un-tiers-de-dechets-en-moins-ramasses-sur-les-bords-de-loire_12310369.html)
>
> 1,6% d'admis **en** moins que l'année dernière [3](http://www.leprogres.fr/france-monde/2017/07/05/bac-78-6-des-eleves-recus-au-premier-tour)
>
> 7 points **de** moins que l’année dernière [4](http://www.leparisien.fr/sports/football/psg/deja-7-points-de-moins-que-l-annee-derniere-05-12-2016-6414216.php)
>
> 4,3 points **de** moins que l’année dernière [5](http://www.vousnousils.fr/2017/07/06/bac-2017-reussite-en-baisse-par-rapport-a-lannee-derniere-sauf-au-bac-techno-605404)
>
> 8,6 kg **de** moins que l’année dernière [6](https://fr.express.live/2017/05/08/venezuela-maduro/)

Cela n'est pas nécessairement une règle générale, mais je pense que l'indifférence entre *de* et *en* est limitée à certains cas, comme lorsqu'ici quand on parle de l'évolution d'une quantité dans le temps, c'est-à-dire de la comparaison d'une quantité entre deux dates ou deux périodes.

Pour d'autres comparaisons, par exemple entre personnes, entre villes, entre pays, on n'a pas le choix d'utiliser *en* à la place de *de*: *il fait dix centimètres **de** plus que moi*, ou *il fait 10 degrés **de** plus à Paris qu'à Brest*, ou *il y a 15 millions d'habitants **de** plus en Allemagne qu'en France*.

Comment: Les deux expressions en soi existent, mais ici "en moins" ne se dit pas.

Comment: @ApplePie - "ici" c'est-à-dire où ?

Comment: Dans l'exemple donné

Comment: @ApplePie Qui dit que ça ne se dit pas ? Quelles sont tes sources ?

Comment: @ApplePie je croyais que tu te référais à un usage régional. J'ai ajouté des sources pour les deux.

Answer (score 0):

> Il y a dix candidats en moins.

mais

> Il y a dix candidats de moins cette année.

Comment: Il y a dix candidats en moins cette année  / Il y a dix candidat de moins cette année. Les deux se disent. C'est une affaire d'opinion et il faudrait justifier.

Answer (score 0):

### Ici il faut utiliser "de moins".

Quand on effectue une comparaison c'est "de moins"/"de plus":

> J'ai deux ans de moins que mon frère.
>
> Elle a eu cinq points de plus que lui à l'examen.

"en moins" s'utilise quand on veut insister sur la valeur négative:

> On lui a volé des billes: il en a deux en moins.
>
> J'ai deux points en moins sur mon permis à cause d'un radar qui m'a prise au dépourvu.

On pourrait donc, pour parler des candidats, dire:

> Il y a dix candidats en moins cette année.

Ce serait mettre l'emphase sur les dix candidats perdus, ce qui est un peu étrange car les candidats ne sont pas les mêmes d'année en année.

D'une manière similaire, on peut utiliser "en plus" pour insister sur l'accumulation, mais en général ce n'est pas pour parler de quantités précises:

> Hier on a failli ne pas avoir assez à manger pour tout le monde: ma belle soeur est venue et en plus ses deux enfants étaient avec elle.

Comment: Une ou des sources pour étayer cette position ?

Comment: @Tensibai Mon expérience de 25 ans sur le terrain.

Comment: Sur quel terrain ? Je dirais bien que je suis en désaccord de part mon expérience de 35 ans sur le terrain (j'ai commencé à parler tôt) mais c'est loin d'être une source de confiance et faisant autorité en la matière...

Comment: @Tensibai: si tu es en désaccord rien ne t'empêche de mettre un "-1" et de poster ta propre réponse.

Comment: Je suis complètement d'accord pour les comparaisons, d'ailleurs il n'y a quasiment aucune occurrence de "en plus que lui" sur le net.

Comment: EDIT: Je suis complètement d'accord pour les comparaisons entre personnes, d'ailleurs il n'y a quasiment aucune occurrence de "en plus que lui" sur les résultats Google, alors que "de plus que lui" est très courant. Les comparaisons entre villes et pays semblent aussi utiliser "de" tout le temps. Mais cette règle ne semble pas s'appliquer aux comparaisons entre périodes — "en plus que l'an dernier" est presque aussi courant dans les résultats Google que "de plus que l'an dernier". Sur cette base je pense que "en" peut s'utiliser quand on parle de l'évolution d'une quantité dans le temps?

Comment: est-ce que la ponctuation est prise en compte dans ces recherches?