# “Du moins” vs. “au moins”

Tags: choix-de-mot, locutions

When you look up ["at least"](https://www.linguee.fr/anglais-francais/traduction/at+least.html) on Linguee, you're shown these examples and their translations:

> **au moins** [...] Nous aurons besoin d'au moins cinq personnes pour le projet.
>
> **du moins** [...] Mon invention devrait fonctionner, du moins en théorie.

If I'm reading this right, "au moins" is for comparing numbers whereas "du moins" is for concessions. Thus, to translate something like the following concession, you'd use "du moins":

> You could accept the offer, even if you end up having to back out. **At least** you'd be sure of having a job lined up for the fall.

However, I usually say "au moins" at this juncture and only started considering "du moins" after seeing it around this site. Maybe I was misled by WordReference, which [only gives "au moins"](http://www.wordreference.com/enfr/at%20least).

- Is there a real distinction or are they conflated in practice?
- If there is a distinction, does my interpretation of the Linguee examples capture it?

---

<sub>There are indeed questions about [similar locutions](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/26436/de-moins-ou-en-moins) but seemingly not about the sense or dichotomy I'm looking for.</sub>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, we could say that "au moins" has 2 meanings.

First, referring to a quantity :

> "J'ai lu **au moins** 50 livres cette année" =>
>   "I've read **at least** 50 books this year"

And the other, referring to the result of another action

> "Appelle-la encore une fois. **Au moins** tu seras sûr"
>   "Call her one last time. **Like this**, you'll be sure"

In this example you could have replaced "Au moins" by "Ainsi" or "Comme cela".

"Du moins" is more used to express the hesitation, and is quite difficult to translate literally in English.

> "Ne t'inquiète pas, il n'aura pas mal, ..., du moins je l'espère"
>   "Don't worry, it won't hurt him, ..., I mean I hope so"

Answer (score 3):

Malgré la définition suivante du [TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/concession) pour le mot concession tel qu'applicable en grammaire,

> « relation de restriction ou d'opposition exprimée par un complément circonstanciel indiquant qu'un phénomène qui en entraîne normalement un autre n'a pas eu cet effet ou a eu un effet contraire »,

Je ne partage pas l'idée qu'une concession soit une restriction ni que « du moins » soit propre à introduire une concession. **« Du moins » introduit une restriction, une nuance, une rectification**, selon le Dictionnaire de l'Académie. Ceci est examiné en même temps que la  [locution « du moins »](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/moins), ci-dessous.

Le Dictionnaire de l'Académie parle seulement d'obstacle en tant qu'élément sémantique dans l'énoncé et non de restriction en tant que relation syntactique : « mention d'une circonstance qui représente un obstacle ou une opposition à l'action principale, mais qui ne l'empêche pas de s'accomplir ».

« Du moins » ne peut pas être considéré exactement en temps qu'élément introduisant une concession ;  prenons l'exemple « Il nous a fallu, du moins pour quelques temps, renoncer au spectacle » ; « bien que » traduit la concession ; donc on aurait « Il nous a fallu, bien que pour quelques temps,… » ; il semble manquer quelque chose ; « mais », qui apporte une rectification, convient à peu près : « Il nous a fallu, mais pour quelques temps,… ». Donc « du moins » est plutôt équivalent à « mais » ; cette relation est appelée plus précisément dans le TLFi une relation de restriction. Puisque selon le TLFi il s'agit d'une concession et selon sa définition (qui semble ne pas convenir), quel est le phénomène sans effet ou à effet contraire ? Il n'y a pas d'implication d'un quelconque phénomène à l'effet contraire auquel il faut renoncer, ni de phénomène qui conduit normalement à renoncer ; « du moins » sert simplement à restreindre une assertion. Prenons un autre exemple : « Vous êtes charmante, belle Raimonde, ou du moins je suis charmé » ; si « je suis charmé » était une concession sur « vous êtes charmante… » on insinuerait un problème dans la relation avec la personne, or ce n'est pas le cas : le locuteur ne fait part d'aucun problème dans la relation mais d'un état d'être personnel ; il n'est pas question d'apposer une condition qui pesée contre la condition d'être charmante pourrait rendre cette condition différente, mais d'émettre un jugement sur l'énonciation « vous êtes charmante », en d'autres termes, de la restreindre ; elle n'est peut être pas tout à fait exacte et le charme est tout simplement subjectif. Une analyse de cette sorte devrait aboutir à cette différence dans tous les cas.

On peut maintenant essayer d'examiner pourquoi « du moins » ne correspond pas à « au moins », que l'on définit selon le TLFi comme signifiant « **en prenant la plus faible estimation** », l'idée de comparaison de nombre, essentielle, étant comprise dans cette définition qui implique aussi les comparaisons où les nombres n'ont plus de sens. Essayons une substitution dans le premier exemple : « Il nous a fallu, au moins pour quelques temps,… ». Où avec « du moins » on précise la portée de « Il nous a fallu renoncer au spectacle. », (pendant quelques temps, ceci étant l'estimation juste),  c'est à dire où avec « du moins » on émet un jugement sur la proposition en la rectifiant, avec « au moins » on introduit la notion d'une durée de temps incertaine qui peut aller de seulement quelques temps à une durée plus grande.

Selon ce point de vue, des équivalents pour les deux phrases sont respectivement les phrases ci-dessous;

- Il nous a fallu renoncer pendant quelques temps.
- Il nous a fallu renoncer pendant quelques temps ou plus.

La définition de « at least » que donne le dictionnaire d'Oxford (voir ci-dessous) confirme que c'est une locution qui correspond aux deux locutions du français qui sont comparées dans cette discussion et que les termes les définissant sont eux-mêmes utilisables directement (et de même leur équivalents français).

- **a)** not less than, at the minimum **b)** at any rate, at all events, if nothing else

*Utilisation des locutions et d'équivalents*

**1**

- Il est de retour, **du moins** c'est ce qu'affirment les gens.
- He is back, **at least** that's what people say.
- He is back, **at all events** that's what people say.

**2**

- Ils ont **au moins** quatre diplômes.
- They have **at least** four diplomas.
- <s>Ils ont quatre diplôme **dans tous les cas**.</s>
- <s>**At any rate**, they have four diplomas.</s>

**Conclusion**
1/ Il existe une véritable distinction et il ne semble pas qu'il existe de par la proximité des sens et les contextes d'utilisation la possibilité que les sens ne fassent qu'un.
2/ Your interpretation corresponds to what I find, in other words, it's correct.

Comment: Very helpful. Then does it strike you that "au moins" is the better choice for my example, that is, "even if the outcome isn't optimal, it will still be good"?

Comment: @LukeSawczak « Vous pourriez accepter cette offre, même si vous avez à faire marche arrière par la suite. Au moins vous seriez sûr d'avoir un travail prêt pour l'automne. »  Yes, « au moins » is the correct choice; other advantages might result, but the minimum of a job in the autumn is a sure thing.

Answer (score 2):

**Au moins**: neutral term to specify a minimal quantity:

> - J'ai besoin d'au moins 10€ pour acheter ça
> - Il y a au moins 500ml dans cette bouteille
> - A mon avis, il pèse au moins 80kg

**Du moins**: (trickier!) A strong assertion is made. *du moins* is then added to precise that there is actually a bit of doubt, or to nuance the assertion. Here's how it can pop up in a sentence:

1. `Je ne suis pas malade.` (I'm not sick)
2. Wait, that's not exactly true: I just *hope* (in French *espérer*) that I'm not sick...
3. `Je ne suis pas malade, du moins je l'espère.`

Another example:

1. `L'explosion va être sans dégats.` (The explosion won't make any damage)
2. Wait, that's not exactly true: I'm only sure that in won't make any damage in theory...
3. `L'explosion va être sans dégats, du moins en théorie.`

*Du moins* is often literally translated to *at least*, but actually it is more used as a replacement for *I mean*.

Comment: It seems like it might be a close equivalent of "or at least", as in "I heard he got a job, or at least an offer."

Comment: Yes, the two are indeed very close (almost interchangeable). But to explain the concept, I'd rather use the *I mean* comparison: *I hear he got the job. Sorry, I mean: an offer.* = *J'ai entendu qu'il a eu le poste, du moins une offre.*

Comment: Makes sense. What do you think of my question in the comment on LPH's offer (since it seems you've both included more or less the same perspective and the same lacune)?

Comment: Yes, you should indeed use *au moins* in your example: *Meme si le résultat n'est pas optimal, au moins il sera bon*.